# How fill a dataframe from another one in R?

Tags: r

I want to fill df2 with information from df1.

df1 as below

```
ID   Mutation
1    A
2    B
2    C
3    A
```

df2 as below

```
ID   A   B   C
1
2
3
```

For example, if mutation A is found in ID 1, then I want it in df2 it marked as "Y".

So the df2 result should be

```
    ID   A   B   C
    1    Y
    2        Y   Y
    3    Y
```

I have hundreds of IDs and more than 20 mutations. How can I efficiently achieve this in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column with value `'Y'` and cast the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = 'Y') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Mutation, values_from = value, values_fill = '')

#     ID A     B     C    
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 "Y"   ""    ""   
#2     2 ""    "Y"   "Y"  
#3     3 "Y"   ""    ""
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Mutation = c("A", "B", 
"C", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` you can try

```
setDT(df)
df2 <- dcast(df,formula = ID~Mutation )
df2[, c("A", "B", "C") := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), " ", "Y")), ID]
df2
#Output
   ID A B C
1:  1 Y    
2:  2   Y Y
3:  3 Y
```